# Improving Java API documentation?

Tags: java, javadoc

What can I do to improve the docs of the official Java API? Is there some convenient way such a wiki site of javadoc allowing people to edit?

If there is none available, what about some tool/script helping document integration? Something which provides auto-integration of javadoc and custom documents, so I can add contents while keeping sync with new API javadoc?

PS: I'm hoping to improve several parts such as JavaFX and Reflection, both lack examples and the latter contains many stub docs such as *Class.getSimpleName() = returns the simple name of class*.

Answer (score 4):

Head over to [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/).  They have a section on 'Hacking the JDK itself' and they accept [patches](http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/).  There is a lot of synergy between OpenJDK and Oracle.

That said, Oracle also have a contribution process outlined [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/community/devmodel-jsp-139764.html).